# Does anyone know of a module like "Artsy Editor" for Drupal?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm looking for a writing interface similar to [Artsy Editor](http://artsyeditor.com/) which is built for Wordpress.

It's a "distraction-free" wysiwyg that I need for a client's site and thus far I've not been able to find one.

Does anyone have suggestions on an existing editor that I can use, or a way to use existing modules to achieve the same effect?

I'm really looking for a way to have a wysiwyg style interface similar to the new "notes" in the new version of basecamp.

The site in question is a Drupal 7 site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no module for Artsy Editor. 
But if you mean inline editor, you can use [**Edit**](http://drupal.org/project/edit) for Drupal 7 and 8 - In-place editing for fields on any entity. Including WYSIWYG editing powered by CKEditor or Aloha.
"Edit" is part of [Spark](http://drupal.org/project/spark) - Drupal distribution which aims to be "the Pressflow of Drupal authoring experience